# how to configure ssh for hadoop standalone installation?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

I am trying to install Hadoop in a standalone mode on my Ubuntu local host.

in this activity, I am using following 2 references.

1)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-in-stand-alone-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04

2)
https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

now this first reference does not speak about any ssh configuration.I am able to implement these instructions successfully also able to execute given 
map-reduce program.

however as instructed in a second reference. we need to configure ssh to enable hadoop to access its nodes.

I followed the instructions given on site.

[image: Tried SSH CONFIGURATION]

although i am not able to connect  to localhost via ssh.

I did a research about the same.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/218344/why-am-i-getting-a-port-22-connection-refused-error

upon firing **sudo netstat -anp | grep sshd** , came to know that sshd is not running.
[image: sshd]

after more of a googeling, I got a suggestion to install openssh-server, which I tried to do. 
***sudo apt-get install openssh-server***

following is the snapshot of error which I got.[image: openssh-server]

my question is why is it not running at my end? 
Am I following right process?
Am I missing any configurations?

thanks,
Ash

Comment: Why aren't you following the actual Hadoop documentation?

Comment: @cricket_007 in actual Hadoop documentation also , they are using the same method to configure ssh connection to localhost. do you think the packages are not installed properly on my linux machine and that is creating this problem?

Comment: I don't think ubuntu comes with ssh pre-installed or enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do so much. It is a damn simple process. You want to ssh with the

'localhost' in the standalone setup. Just follow to simple commands.

```
ssh-keygen
```

Make sure you press enter on every default setting.

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub localhost
```

You will be asked for the password once. Enter it and then try ssh with localhost using command

```
ssh localhost
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: SSH should be password-less, though, according to Hadoop docs

Comment: @Abhinav for ssh-keygen , I passed default values. when it asked  passphrase  , I simply pressed enter to pass empty value. pattern got generated. then  I fired   **ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub localhost** , first i got the info message as "attempting to log in with new keys to filter out any that are already installed " then same error message as "ssh: connect to host localhost port 22 : Connection refused"

Comment: Which means your port number 22 is not free. You have to free your port. You can take help of internet about how to free a port number using firewall commands. Or else check if there is any other app using this port. 'netstat -ntpl | grep 22' use this command and see the results. If any process is using this port then kill it with 'kill -9 <process_id>' . However, your query has been answered. So you can accept the answer

Comment: **netstat -ntpl | grep 22** returns nothing in my case. anyways thanks for your ssh explanation.